# How do I name the indexes of this dataseries without repeating myself too much

Tags: pandas

I have a dataseries that looks like this:

```
NEW QUARTERLY ESTIMATES - After rebasing     GDP (seasonally adjusted)

2009                                                          1314844
Unnamed: 3                                                    1326084
Unnamed: 4                                                    1348808
Unnamed: 5                                                    1371285
2010                                                          1414539
Unnamed: 7                                                    1438482
Unnamed: 8                                                    1449582
Unnamed: 9                                                    1490081
2011                                                          1501464
Unnamed: 11                                                   1512220
Unnamed: 12                                                   1527277
Unnamed: 13                                                  1548587
```

I want to name the unnamed rows with the year above it so for instance, unnamed:3 to unnamed:5 should be 2009 and so forth, how do i do that

The only thing I can think of is creating a dictionary and using the rename method on pandas. Is there a scalable way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test 4 digits values:

```
m = df['NEW QUARTERLY ESTIMATES - After rebasing'].str.contains('\d{4}')
```

Or test if not contains `Unnamed` with invert mask by `~`:

```
m = ~df['NEW QUARTERLY ESTIMATES - After rebasing'].str.contains('Unnamed')
```

And then pass to [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with forward filling missing values:

```
df['NEW QUARTERLY ESTIMATES - After rebasing'] = df['NEW QUARTERLY ESTIMATES - After rebasing'].where(m).ffill()
print (df)

   NEW QUARTERLY ESTIMATES - After rebasing  GDP (seasonally adjusted)
0                                      2009                    1314844
1                                      2009                    1326084
2                                      2009                    1348808
3                                      2009                    1371285
4                                      2010                    1414539
5                                      2010                    1438482
6                                      2010                    1449582
7                                      2010                    1490081
8                                      2011                    1501464
9                                      2011                    1512220
10                                     2011                    1527277
11                                     2011                    1548587
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df['your_col_name'] = pd.to_numeric(
    df['your_col_name'], errors='coerce').ffill(downcast='int')
```